# fmap a 2-arity function on Nothing should return Nothing?

Tags: haskell, ghci

From the source of `Maybe` in [ghc](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs#L844):

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap _ Nothing  = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a) = Just (f a)
```

When `fmap` is applied to `Nothing`, it should return `Nothing`.

For example, run this in ghci (v8.2.2):

```
Prelude> fmap (+1) Nothing
Nothing
```

However, when I apply a function with an arity of 2:

```
Prelude> fmap (++) Nothing
<interactive>:11:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show ([a0] -> [a0]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

In fact, the result seems to be `Nothing`:

```
Prelude> import Data.Maybe
Prelude Data.Maybe> isNothing $ fmap (++) Nothing
True
```

My question is, does `fmap (++) Nothing` really return `Nothing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `fmap f Nothing = Nothing` no matter what `f` is or what type it has. The `Show` instance for `Maybe` looks like

```
instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) where
  ...
```

So you can't `show` or `print` a value of type `Maybe (A -> B)` because functions don't have a `Show` instance.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Let's look at the types:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

so,

```
fmap (++) :: Functor f => f [a] -> f ([a] -> [a])
```

`fmap` takes a 1-arity function. However, in Haskell a 2-arity function is just a 1-arity function that returns another 1-arity function:

```
([a] -> [a] -> [a]) ~ ([a] -> ([a] -> [a]))
```

so your `fmap (++) :: Maybe [a] -> Maybe ([a] -> [a])`

If you pass `Nothing` to this, it returns `Nothing`. If you pass `Just "foo"` (for example), it returns `Just` a function that takes a string and prepends `"foo"` to it:

```
Prelude> Just f = fmap (++) $ Just "foo"
Prelude> f "bar"
"foobar"
```

The reason you get an error is because GHCi tries to print the output, meaning the output must implement the `Show` typeclass. What it's trying to `show` is `Nothing :: Maybe ([a] -> [a])`. The type system doesn't know it just has to print `Nothing`, all it knows is it can't `show` an `[a] -> [a]`. So it prints the error.

Comment: Thank for very much for the detailed answer!